# File gets corrupted after sending it with HttpPost

Tags: java, file, base64, httprequest

what I try to do is, sending data as a String to one of my external Servers. But after I set up the Request, the file on my filesystem gets corrupted.

Here is how I read my file into a String

```
File file = new File("/some/path/on/my/hdd/testimg.png");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] binaryData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
fis.read(binaryData);
String content = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(binaryData);
fis.close();
```

And here is how I do the POST-Request:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("some.url");
... some headers ...
request.setEntity(new StringEntity(this.body)); // this.body is the String
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request); // HERE THE FILE GETS CORRUPTED
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
this.result = IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8");
```

Can someone tell my  why the file `/some/path/on/my/hdd/testimg.png` on my harddisk gets corrupted after I send the request?

Thanks in advice!

Comment: use `Content-Type: image/png`.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say that the file on your *local* filesystem is corrupted after the request, there are only few possibilities:

- It is already corrupted beforehand
- There's another place in the program which writes the file
- If the server you send the request to is running on the same machine, the application running on the server might be to blame

Comment: I found the solution. It's one of the points you mentioned.
The server I send the request to runs on the same local machine, at it was overwriting the data. Its fixed now.